# Improper integral test

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am looking for a reference for this fact (or a proof):

The Improper integral $\int_{1}^\infty f(x) dx $, where $f$ is positive and continuous, exists if $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log f(x)}{\log x}=n$ where $n\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $n<-1$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For small $\varepsilon >0$ and $x $ big enough (say $x>m $), $\log f (x)/\log x <n+\varepsilon <r <-1 $, and then $\log f (x)<\log x^r $, so $f (x)<x^r $. Thus
$$
\int_m^\infty f (x)\,dx\leq\int_m^\infty x^r\,dx <\infty.
$$